# Where do I add UITableViewCell's to the SECOND section of this UITableView?

Tags: uiview, uitableview

There's going to be a lot of code in this, and for that I apologize, but the very problem is that I'm having difficulty stepping my way through this program and ascertaining where this thing is creating the sections of the UITableView.

This started off as a table view exercise from 'iOS Programming:  The Big Nerd Ranch Guide' and I decided I wanted to explore this more, so I created some images in Illustrator and went to town.

I've successfully created:

- the UIView
- the UITableView and UITableViewCell's in ONE SINGLE SECTION, that are filled with "Items," which are just randomly generated strings, as in the book example.  (random adjective, random noun, random serial number, etc.)
- miscellaneous buttons that change to a highlighted state when you tap them
- a footer after the first and only section that displays a few more buttons that seem to work fine

All I'm trying to do now, as an exercise, is take half of these randomly generated string items, stick 'em in table view cells, and place them in **section 2** of the table view.  Seems like a relatively straightforward task, but I cannot figure out where/how to do this.  I've read the documentation and I think I may need to implement the insertSections:withRowAnimation: method, but I can't find an example online anywhere that gives me a clue as to how to implement it in a way that makes sense in my program.

To shortcut things--hopefully-I believe the problem's going to lie in the ItemsViewController.m file, located at the bottom of this post.  The ItemStore class is just an array called 'allItems' which holds the randomly generated string items I described before.  Nothing important to what I'm trying to do seems to be happening in the AppDelegate files either.  Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks so much in advance.

ItemStore.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@class Item;

@interface ItemStore : NSObject {
    NSMutableArray *allItems;
}

+(ItemStore *)sharedStore;
-(NSMutableArray *)allItems;
-(Item *)createItem;

@end
```

ItemStore.m

```
#import "ItemStore.h"
#import "Item.h"

@implementation ItemStore

// create the singleton ItemStore
+(ItemStore *)sharedStore {
    static ItemStore *sharedStore = nil;
    if (!sharedStore)
        sharedStore = [[super allocWithZone:nil] init];        
    return sharedStore;
}

+(id)allocWithZone:(NSZone *)zone {
    return [self sharedStore];
}

-(id)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        allItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }
    return self;
}

-(NSArray *)allItems {
    return allItems;
}

-(Item *)createItem {
    Item *p = [Item randomItem];
    [allItems addObject:p];

    return p;
}

@end
```

AppDelegate.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class ItemsViewController;

@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;

@property (strong, nonatomic) ItemsViewController *viewController;

@end
```

AppDelegate.m

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "ItemsViewController.h"
#import "Item.h"

@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

    ItemsViewController *itemsViewController = [[ItemsViewController alloc] init];
    UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:itemsViewController];
    [[self window] setRootViewController:navController];

    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}

- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application {}
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application {}
- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application {}
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {}
- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application {}

@end
```

ItemsViewController.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface ItemsViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>

{
    UIView *underView;
    UITableView *ivarTableView;
}

@property (nonatomic, readwrite) UITableView *ivarTableView;

-(id)init;
-(id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style;
-(void)insertSections:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath withRowAnimation:(UITableViewRowAnimation)animation;
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;

@end
```

ItemsViewController.m

```
#import "ItemsViewController.h"
#import "Item.h"
#import "ItemStore.h"

@implementation ItemsViewController

@synthesize ivarTableView;

-(void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    CGFloat startingPoint = 33.0;
    CGRect bounds = self.view.bounds;
    bounds.origin.y = startingPoint;
    bounds.size.height -= startingPoint;

    self.ivarTableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:bounds style:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
    self.ivarTableView.dataSource = self;
    self.ivarTableView.delegate = self;
    self.ivarTableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleSingleLine;
    self.ivarTableView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
    [self.view addSubview:self.ivarTableView];

    // create background, custom navigation bar, and a few other images/buttons, 
    // and some buttons that get placed in the footer.  all of these work fine.
    // ...

-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForFooterInSection: (NSInteger) section
{
    // this method is a little unclear to me, but I've got everything in the footer working fine, so I haven't worried about it at this point.
    return 0.0;
}

// so far, init{} just creates a random amount of 'Items', which are just random strings so there's something to populate the UITableViewCells.
-(id) init {
    if (self) {
        int r = arc4random() % 10;
        NSLog(@"Number of cells in the table view should be:  %d", r);
        for (int i = 1; i <= r; i++) {
            [[ItemStore sharedStore] createItem];
        }
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)insertSections:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath withRowAnimation:(UITableViewRowAnimation)animation{
    // I think this is where I need to--create another section?--and send the second section the data that is going to be used in the second section's cells, but I'm having trouble tracing the flow of this program.
}

// Asks the delegate for the height to use for a row in a specified location and sends
// the appropriate size, based upon which image is going to be displayed for the particular cell.
// Top cell is a taller height, middle and bottom cell(s) are the same height.
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    NSInteger lastRow = [self tableView:ivarTableView numberOfRowsInSection:1] - 1;
    NSInteger rowsAmount = [self tableView:ivarTableView numberOfRowsInSection:[indexPath section]];

    if (indexPath.row == 0 && rowsAmount != 1) {
        return 95.0;
    } else if (indexPath.row == 0 && rowsAmount == 1) {
        return 137.0;
    } /*end change*/ else if (indexPath.row == lastRow) {
        return 74.0;
    } else {
        return 74.0;
    }
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
        cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"UITableViewCell"];

    if (!cell) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                                   reuseIdentifier:@"UITableViewCell"];
    }

    NSInteger sectionsAmount = [tableView numberOfSections];
    NSInteger rowsAmount = [self tableView:ivarTableView numberOfRowsInSection:[indexPath section]];

    if (rowsAmount == 1) {
        cell.backgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"cellTypeOne.png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:0.0 topCapHeight:5.0]];

        cell.selectedBackgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"cellTypeOneTouched.png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:0.0 topCapHeight:5.0]];

    } else if (rowsAmount == 2) {

        if ([indexPath section] == 0 && [indexPath row] == 0) {

            cell.backgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"cellTypeOneMulti.png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:0.0 topCapHeight:5.0]];

            cell.selectedBackgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"cellTypeOneMultiTouched.png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:0.0 topCapHeight:5.0]];
        } else {

            cell.backgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"cellBottom.png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:0.0 topCapHeight:5.0]];

            cell.selectedBackgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"cellBottomTouched.png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:0.0 topCapHeight:5.0]];
        }

    } else if (rowsAmount >= 3) {

        if ([indexPath section] == 0 && [indexPath row] == 0){

            cell.backgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"cellTypeOneMulti.png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:0.0 topCapHeight:5.0]];

            cell.selectedBackgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"cellTypeOneMultiTouched.png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:0.0 topCapHeight:5.0]];            

        } else if ([indexPath section] == sectionsAmount - 1 && [indexPath row] == rowsAmount - 1) {

            cell.backgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"cellBottom.png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:0.0 topCapHeight:5.0]];

            cell.selectedBackgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"cellBottomTouched.png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:0.0 topCapHeight:5.0]];

        } else {

            cell.backgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"cellMiddle.png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:0.0 topCapHeight:5.0]];

            cell.selectedBackgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"cellMiddleTouched.png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:0.0 topCapHeight:5.0]];
            }
        }

    // gets rid of the white box that would bound the text of the cell
    [[cell contentView] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [[cell backgroundView] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [cell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

    /* Set the text of the cell to the description of the item that is at the nth index of items, where n = row this cell will appear in on the tableView */
    Item *p = [[[ItemStore sharedStore] allItems] objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
    [[cell textLabel] setText:[p description]];
    [[cell textLabel] setHighlightedTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    [[cell textLabel] setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;

    return cell;
}

/* return count of ItemStore's allItems array */
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [[[ItemStore sharedStore] allItems] count];
}

// ...

@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An UITableView asks for the cell for a specific section and row, calling the method

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableViewcellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

from its "Data Source".

In this case, the data source is ItemsViewController. So in the mentioned method, one of the arguments is "indexPath", wich is the object that indicates for what section and row you have to return a cell.

You can know if it is calling for the section 2 comparing:

```
if(indexPath.section == 2)
{
    //Do something for section 2
}
```

EDIT:

Also, to get a table with two section, you have to implement the method

```
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 2; //Return the number of sections you what
}
```

in ItemsViewControlle.m .

Good Luck!

Comment: This is exactly what I needed.  Thanks so very much, LuisEspinoza!  I can't believe it was that simple.  If only you could buy experience.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see the following method in your code, which is the one your tableview will call to know how many section it should create.

```
    - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return numberOfSectionYouWant;
}
```

Also it would be better for you to make your controller a subclass of `UITableViewController` instead of a `UIViewController` where you add protocols. it will save you many mistakes.

```
insertSections:withRowAnimation:
```

can be called directly on your tableview afterward if you need to add a section during runtime.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, Nicolas.  Implementing numberOfSectionsInTableView: was exactly what I needed to do.  About the latter part of your response, I was having a difficult time with the view controller being a subclass of UITableViewController.  That's how I had it set initially, but I changed it at Ismael's recommendation in this poast:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13571687/how-do-you-make-a-uitableview-smaller-programmatically/13571839#13571839

Comment: yeah that's what I did in some situation.